# The Julia way of merging vector of pairs into a dictionary

Tags: julia

So I have a vector `[:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :a=>12, :b=>33]`, so I would like to convert it into `Dict(:a=>[1, 12], :b=>[a, 33], :c=>[3])` which the ordering of elements need not to be preserved.

Also the type of dictionary can be `Dict{Symbol, T}` which `T` is any type of collections, iterators or generators.

I know how to do it using a for loop insertions, but it seems not the best practice in Julia, so I would like to know are there some combinations of functions or packages I could use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way:

```
julia> v= [:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :a=>12, :b=>33]
5-element Vector{Pair{Symbol, Int64}}:
 :a => 1
 :b => 2
 :c => 3
 :a => 12
 :b => 33

EDIT: Inspired by mcabbott comment:

julia> foldl(v; init=Dict{Symbol,Vector{Int}}()) do d,(k,v)
           push!(get!(()->Int[], d, k), v); d
       end
Dict{Symbol, Vector{Int64}} with 3 entries:
  :a => [1, 12]
  :b => [2, 33]
  :c => [3]

# ADDED: Inspired by August answer

julia> using OrderedCollections

julia> foldl(v; init=Dict{Symbol,Vector{Int}}()) do d,(k,v)
           mergewith!(append!, d, LittleDict(k=>[v]))
       end
Dict{Symbol, Vector{Int64}} with 3 entries:
  :a => [1, 12]
  :b => [2, 33]
  :c => [3]

# Original answer

julia> foldl(v; init=Dict{Symbol,Vector{Int}}()) do d,(k,v)
           setindex!(d, push!(get(d, k, Int[]), v), k)
       end
Dict{Symbol, Vector{Int64}} with 3 entries:
  :a => [1, 12]
  :b => [2, 33]
  :c => [3]
```

Note this uses some nice Julia features such as:

- `do` syntax
- destructuring parameters (as in `d, (k, v)`)
- `get` with default return value
- `push!` and `setindex!` return value is mutated collection
- `get!` setting default value (from mcabbott)
- `mergewith!` to combine dicts (from August)

And, doing it in a `for` loop as suggested in the question is perfectly acceptable and efficient, and sometimes more readable.

Comment: One more nice feature is `get!`, which combines `get` & `setindex!`, and only calls the default case when needed. Replace the middle line with `push!(get!(() -> Int[], d, k), v); d`. I think the code above calls `Int[]` 5 times, but only needs 3.

Comment: Oh! It works! Thanks for the suggestions from all of you!
Since I would like to have more one liner in the code, the codebase not for technical things it a scientific research project so I would like to keep things simple and intuitive.

After I tested, the 3 methods are on par with each other in terms of performance, I think at last its up to one's flavor.

Answer (score 2):

Short but probably not so fast:

```
julia> v = [:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :a=>12, :b=>33];

julia> mergewith(append!, [Dict(p[1] => [p[2]]) for p in v]...)
Dict{Symbol, Vector{Int64}} with 3 entries:
  :a => [1, 12]
  :b => [2, 33]
  :c => [3]
```

Comment: Added a version inspired by your answer (see in my answer). Using `LittleDict` from `OrderedCollection` actually makes it fast. Might be faster than other methods.